# What to do with Question Marks in HTAccess Redirects

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm new to redirects and have researched how to do this but am just getting more and more confused.

What I'm wanting to do is create a rule to redirect:

From: http://www.example.com/wordpress/?p=1250
To: http://www.otherexample.com/blog

Where I'm running into issues is with the question mark. I've read somewhere that  I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly, but here's what I have so far:

```
**Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=1297$ 
RewriteRule    ^wordpress$  linktoothersite    [R=301, QSA, L, NC]**
```

I'm failing somewhere, any of you see what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. I could only post two links, so link to other site would be the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single link you want to change you don't need a htaccess rule for that you can just do a redirect.

```
redirect 301 /wordpress/?p=250 http://www.othersite.com/blog
```

If the URL parameter changes you can use this rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*) http://www.othersite.com/blog [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Note that when you use the `QSA` flag it will append the URL with the query parameter so if that's what you want the resulting URL will be.

```
http://www.othersite.com/blog?p=250
```

Otherwise if you remove the `QSA` flag, then it will just redirect to this

```
http://www.othersite.com/blog
```

Comment: Oh awesome! That really helped me with that example. In the same vein, I've also got the following style: